# Is it possible to play a rtmp livestream in android app

Tags: android, rtmp, live-streaming

Does anyone know if it’s possible to play a rtmp stream with exoplayer.

I’ve tried this but didn’t manage to get it working:

```java
ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
playerView.setPlayer(player);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("rtmp://192.168.109.84/live");
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri);
        
RtmpDataSource.Factory rtmpDataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSource.Factory();        
MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(rtmpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
        
player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);        
player.prepare();
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Exoplayer has a demo app as part of their open source project. In the demo there are a number of different sample streams. If there is an rtmp stream you could try swapping out the url for your one, and seeing if that works. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: You can use https://github.com/bilibili/ijkplayer which supports RTMP/HLS/RTSP etc. If want use Exoplayer, you can use a media server to convert RTMP to HLS, such as https://github.com/ossrs/srs